# Why Zxing.net can't decode these qr codes?

Tags: c#, .net, qr-code, zxing

I'm trying to decode qr codes in tiff frames. I crop right-bottom quarter of frame.

```
System.Drawing.Rectangle section = new        System.Drawing.Rectangle(barcodeBitmap.Width / 2, barcodeBitmap.Height / 2, barcodeBitmap.Width, barcodeBitmap.Height);
System.Drawing.Bitmap croppedBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(section.Width, section.Height);
System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(croppedBitmap);
g.DrawImage(barcodeBitmap, 0, 0, section, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

It can decode this cropped section

[image]

But it can't decode these ones.

[image]
[image]

The code I'm using is this

```
IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
var barcodeBitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(path);
var result = reader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);
if (result != null)
{
  var Text = result.Text;
}
```

What can I do for better decoding?

Comment: Is that image is original image that you scan?
I download it and that image quality is so poor.

Comment: the size is 237 x 333 px but when you cropped just QR Code and resize it, using higher pixel, the QR image is not good.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the property `TryHarder`, which will make `ZXing` spend more time to try to find a barcode. It optimizes accuracy, not speed:

```
 var reader = new ZXing.BarcodeReader { TryHarder = true };
```

Comment: @JBKing this is the author answer to his own question.

Comment: Given the initial wording of the answer, I read it more as a comment than an answer to the question. It has since been quite edited making my initial comment moot.

Answer (score 0):

If your reader is meant to decode QrCodes specifically then you should use a more targeted reader. Ive used this code for scanning qrcodes on WP7+ apps with no issue.

```
using ZXing;
using ZXing.Client.Result;
using ZXing.Common;
using ZXing.QrCode;
....
var reader= new ZXing.QrCode.QRCodeReader();
var barcodeBitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(path);
var result = reader.decode(barcodeBitmap);
if (result != null)
{
  var text = result.Text;
}
```

Other wise you can use a more general approach,

```cs
var reader = new MultiFormatReader();
var barcodeBitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(path);
var result = reader.decode(barcodeBitmap);
if (result != null)
{
  var format = result.BarcodeFormat;
  var parsedResult = ResultParser.parseResult(result);
  var type = parsedResult.Type;
  var text = result.Text;
  ....
}
```

Comment: 'cuse me, but are you using `ZXing.Net` in this question? http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Blaise yes. look at the namespaces in the first code snippet.

Comment: In `(Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(path);` is that `Bitmap` from `System.Drawing` or from `ZXing`? My `reader.decode()` asks for a `BinaryBitmap` type parameter.

Comment: I would usually use a `BinaryBitmap` as well. If you are having issues post a question and send me the link in the comments. I'll give it a look when I get a chance.